# Firebase orderbykey in the nested childs

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the root of the Firebase with nested children which are ordered by keys. My data structure is like this:

```
"-Ka3rbdLvH0I8X1Lg4of" : {
    "menus" : {
      "-KaD6U8_n5CPbRmAhgM2" : {
        "menuItems" : {
          "-KaD6UEoDvrm1W1a55AR" : {
            "name" : "Annemin Kahvaltısı"
          },
          "-KaD6UKf0DyPja-Rni0X" : {
            "name" : "Sıcak Kahvaltı",
          },
          "-KaD6UQyrJ1p5Ok9oya4" : {
            "name" : "Anadolu Kahvaltısı",
          },
        "name" : "Sahanda Ürünler"
      },
      "-KaD6VgvHIj37Qyrirw1" : {
        "menuItems" : {
          "-KaD6Von-sz1xqPLeI5I" : {
            "name" : "Sade Omlet",
          },
          "-KaD6Vvg0cOBFuABbtuU" : {
            "name" : "Mantarlı Omlet",
          },       
        "name" : "Omletler"
      },
```

I have a `restaurant -> menus -> menuItems`. A `restaurant` can have multiple `menus` and a `menus` can have multiple `menuitems`. They inserted with specific Firebase keys. The code, I am getting the data as

```
    mDatabase.child("restaurants").child(lastResIdFirebaseKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            currentRest = snapshot.getValue(Restaurant.class);
            tv_resName.setText(currentRest.getName());
            tv_resDesc.setText(currentRest.getAddress());
            iv_resImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_restaurant);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

In my java class implementations; I am mapping the child nodes to hasmap like;

```
    public HashMap<String,Menu> menus;
```

The Restaurant class

```
public class Restaurant {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    public HashMap<String,Menu> menus;

    public Restaurant() {}

    public Restaurant(String name, String descriptioArrayList<Menu> menus)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Menu> getMenus() {
        return menus;
    }

    public void setMenus(HashMap<String, Menu> menus) {

        this.menus = menus;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine, I am successfully getting the `restaurant` root and mapping it to class. But, the `menu` and `menuitems` order are not in the same order as they are inserted from Firebase.

I have checked the datasnapshot, they are coming from Firebase unordered. I know the `orderbykey()` or `getChildren()` gets the data with the inserted order, but I am trying to do for the order both children `menus` and `menuitems`.

To sum up, I want to get whole `restaurant` root, its `menus` and `menuitems` the order that I inserted them. I want to do this only by getting `restaurant` root. Is there any way to do that? Thank you.

EDIT: Added the Restaurant.class and JSON version of the data uploaded.

Comment: Please consider uploading exported JSON data instead of a screenshot of your database. Your implementation of the `Restaurant.class` would be helpful too.

Comment: I think this way more visually understandable. But i will edit the question.

Comment: Images should only be uploaded if there is **no** other way of explaining what you mean. I am referring to this question and its answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: If you're okay to sort it locally (inside your code), check out this object called `SortedList` that give a breeze on organizing sorted list. But if you must sort it on server, it might be more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mDatabase.child("restaurants").child("restaurant_key").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ArrayList<Menu> menuArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(DataSnapshot menu : dataSnapshot.child("menus").getChildren()) {
                ArrayList<String> menuItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot menuItem :  menu.child("menuItems").getChildren()) {
                    menuItemArrayList.add(menuItem.child("name").getValue().toString());
                }
                menuArrayList.add(new Menu(menu.child("name").getValue().toString(), menuItemArrayList));
            }
            currentRes = new Restaurant(dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), dataSnapshot.child("description").getValue().toString(), menuArrayList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) { }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { }
    });
```

If you do not understand what I'm doing please comment and I'll edit my answer.